# Java String to short hash code

Tags: java, hash

I want to "implement" a hash function from Strings to shorts, using the java standard `hashCode()` function of String object. I came up with the following simple implementation:

```
static short shortHashCode(String str)
{
   int strHashCode = str.hashCode();
   short shorterHashCode = (short) (strHashCode % Short.MAX_VALUE);
   return shorterHashCode;
}
```

1. Is my `shortHashCode` function a good hash function? Meaning is the chance of collisions small (chance that two different Strings will have the same hash code close to 1/Short.MAX_VALUE) ?
2. Is there a better way to implement hash function from Strings to shorts?

Comment: Yes! a hash function must return the same hash code for identical inputs

Comment: As far as chances are concerned, there are a possibility of 32768 different short values returned.  The chances are completely depended on the input set.  If you use a random generator, then it depends on what statistic model that generator is based off (does each value have an equal chance or do some values have higher chances over others, etc.).

Comment: Lets just say equal chance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review and opinion on working code. It is off-topic here as ( too broad and opinion based ) and should probably be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, I think the question more relates to convert between two language-specific primitives while preserving the useful semantic properties of the original.  That seems on-topic to me.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Because the mod operator in Java can return a negative number if the arguments are negative, I think there are a possibility of 65535 different short values returned. (It would be 65536, but I can't get it to return -32768, so I think it's 2^16-1.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(short) (strHashCode % Short.MAX_VALUE);
```

is losing information unnecessarily.

```
 (short) (strHashCode % ((Short.MAX_VALUE + 1) << 1));
```

would not, but would be equivalent anyway to

```
 (short) strHashCode
```

since casting an integral type to a smaller integral type just truncates the most significant bits.

---

It also assumes that all bits have the same entropy, which may not be true.  You could try and spread the entropy around:

```
 (short) (strHashCode ^ (strHashCode >>> 16))
```

which XORs the high 16 bits with the low 16 bits.

---

> Meaning is the chance of collisions small (chance that two different Strings will have the same hash code close to 1/Short.MAX_VALUE) ?

`java.lang.String.hashCode` is not a [cryptographically strong hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), so it only has that property if an attacker can't control one or both inputs to force a collision.

If you expose it to strings from an untrusted source, you might see a much higher rate of hash collisions, possibly allowing an attacker to deny service.

Also, it is designed to tradeoff a small increase in collision rate for better performance, and cross-version stability.  There are better string hashing functions out there.

Comment: Some examples showing that generating collisions for `String.hascCode` is pretty easy: http://david-soroko.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/generating-collisions-in-stringhashcode.html